# Is there a way to use Spark Structured Streaming to calculate daily aggregates?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am planning to use structured streaming to calculate daily aggregates across different metrics.

Data volume < 1000 records per day.

Here is the simple example of input data

```
timestamp, Amount
1/1/20 10:00, 100
1/1/20 11:00, 200
1/1/20 23:00, 400
1/2/20 10:00, 100
1/2/20 11:00, 200
1/2/20 23:00, 400
1/2/20 23:10, 400
```

Expected output

```
Day, Amount
1/1/20, 700
1/2/20, 1100
```

I am planning to do something like this in the structured streaming not sure if it works or if it's the right way to do it?

`parsedDF.withWatermark("date", "25 hours").groupBy("date", window("date", "24 hours")).sum("amount")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is material overhead from running structured streams. Given you're writing code to produce a single result every 24 hours it would seem a better use of resources to do the following if you can take an extra couple minutes of latency in trade for using far fewer resources.

- Ingest data into a table, partitioned by day
- Write a simple SQL query against this table to generate your daily aggregate(s)
- Schedule the job to run [watermark] seconds after midnight.

That's with the impression you're in the default output mode since you didn't specify one. If you want to stick with streaming, more context in your code and what your goal is would be helpful. For example, how often do you want results, and do you need partial results before the end of the day? How long do you want to wait for late data to update aggregates? What output mode are you planning to use?

Comment: Note: This assumes that data arriving "seconds before midnight" has completely been flushed to disk. Also, ignores the definition of "midnight" for any specific timezone

Comment: Yes, giving data time to arrive is a reason for watermarks (e.g., 300 seconds). The need for an assumption on when to finalize an aggregation is a trade-off using the batch approach to save on resources/cost. You can restate numbers later, use a large watermark, or another scheme. Midnight is naturally defined as the end of the day for each of the author's daily aggregations. Regarding that detail, I could see parameterized jobs with time zone as one parameter, running it once for the data generators in each time zone/partition. The window() above respects `spark.sql.session.timeZone`.

Comment: @KyleWhite Thanks for the answer. Instead of using structured streaming with state. I am planning to use structured streaming w/o state and merge processed results into delta table. while merging the results I will update the aggregations if there are any existing records with the same date using update set. This way I can avoid running it continuously. I am also thinking about using Delta Live tables as another option

Comment: @VinayEmmadi How did that go? If able, please do share if it was a viable alternative and what you learned from trying the approach.

Comment: @KyleWhite I have not implemented this yet. But I felt it is far better to just do that with MERGE in Delta Lake than a watermarked aggregation on the stream itself. I will just incrementally add the aggregates from the single batch to the row value in the table.